# difference between two columns between two sql table

Tags: mysql, join

I have
donors table

```
ID  BG  amount                                                            

1   A   7
                                                                          
2   A   5
                                                                          
3   A+  8
                                                                          
4   A+  4
                                                                          
5   A   6
```

and acceptors table

```
ID  BG  amount

1   A+  9

2   A   7

3   A+  10

4   A   5

5   A+  7
```

I want to find out different blood group's where amount of acceptors are more than donors and by how much amount deficiency

o/p:

```
A+ 14
```

Comment: Have you tried writing a query yet?  The best way to learn SQL (or any programming language) is to practice using it.

Comment: Please clarify the question. Are you asking for the sum of all A+ donor records to be compared to the sum of all A+ acceptor records? How did you arrive at the fact that A+ is 14? What does "o/p" mean?

Comment: @DavidMedinets o/p means output i guess

Comment: Select a.bg, sum(a.amount)-sum(d.amount) as diff
from accepros a join donors d
on a.id=b.id
having diff>0
group by bg;
I tried to run this query

Comment: im not a sql pro or something but try this? `select bg,amount from accepters,donors acceptors.amount > donors.amount;`

Comment: *I tried to run this query* 1) HAVING clause must be placed after GROUP BY clause. 2) Join multiplying will give wrong balance (`diff`) value - nevertheless the BG with positive balance will be obtained correctly.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT bg,sum(diff) FROM 
(SELECT BG,-amount AS diff FROM donor 
UNION ALL 
SELECT  BG,amount AS diff FROM acceptor) 
GROUP BY bg having sum(diff)>0;
```

Comment: is that an unwanted `-` in line 2?

Comment: No, It should be negative.

Comment: @CoolCloud He asked about the diff between two.

Comment: thanks @Akina, I updated the query based on your comment.